# Annotation based JMX

Tags: java, playframework, guice, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

How would you implement Spring like annotation based JMX feature. If class is marked by `@ManagedResource` methods of the class marked with `@ManagedOperation` are automatically exposed via JMX.

I would like to avoid creating interfaces with MBean notation. I'm using Play with Guice framework. The naive approach first comes to mind:

- Iterate over all classes managed by Guice
- If class is marked with annotation, create new interface which fits MBean notation. Amend class, amended class should implement new created interface.
- Register instance of the class in MBean server.

Second step will be done using byte code manipulation tool, for example ASM. Is it possible to do it with ASM ? How would you implement such feature ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you don't need an interface.  MBeans are entirely described by metadata. You can implement your own custom implementation of [DynamicMBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/DynamicMBean.html) which returns the appropriate description of your management "interface" (without actually creating said interface).  no crazy byte code manipulation necessary, just basic reflection.

Comment: great, this is slightly easier =)